# Numpy Linalg Solve Broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

I have an N by 2 by 2 numpy matrix A. For all i in {0...,N-1}, I want to compute:

solve(Ai, b)

Where B is 2 by 2 and Ai=A[i,:,:]. I tried to do this in numpy using np.linalg.solve using what I thought were correct broadcasting operations in the following code (the A and b below are just for demonstration purposes, the actual matrix A is much larger):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[2,3],[5,6]],[[3,4],[5,6]]])
b = np.eye(2)
np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (3,2,2)->(3,newaxis) (2,2)->(2,newaxis) and requested shape (2)
```

I am a little confused... I have used numpy broadcasting before and never had issues doing operations of this nature in the past... does anyone know what I have done wrong here?

Comment: What does `solve` say about using `N` square arrays?  It's not a operator or ufunc, so doesn't follow broadcasting rules the usual sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve N different systems of equations, in fact you are passing an N×2×2 matrix A, but only a 2×2 matrix b. That's what the error is referring to when saying operands cannot be *broadcast together*.

If you want to solve `Ai x = b` for all i from 0 to N-1, where Ai is 2×2, then you also need `b` with shape N×2×K (N×2×2 in you case).

Something like will work, assuming you always want `b = eye(2)`:

```
>>> A = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[2,3],[5,6]],[[3,4],[5,6]]])
>>> b = np.array([np.eye(2),np.eye(2),np.eye(2)])
>>> np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

And this is the output:

```
array([[[-2.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.5       , -0.5       ]],

       [[-2.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 1.66666667, -0.66666667]],

       [[-3.        ,  2.        ],
        [ 2.5       , -1.5       ]]])
```